# Full-width div with background color

Tags: css, background

On this page: http://www.tff-bvba.be, I need the grey background behind the picture to be full-width on all resolutions, and the text and picture to be centered on the screen. Everything works ok, except the fact that the background continues to the right, off the screen (scroll to the right, you'll see).

I spent 2 hours looking for a solution but found none that worked for me... This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wide">
<div class="odd">
<div class="homeimage"><img src="http://www.tff-bvba.be/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/hugo-  home.png" alt="hugo-home" class="alignright size-full wp-image-1283" /></div>
<div class="hometext"><h1>Slaag in je materiaalinnovatie</h1>
Plan je een complexe innovatie waarbij de <b>combinatie en vorm van materialen</b> essentieel is? Missen je medewerkers <i>knowhow</i> of heb je tijdelijk versterking nodig?<br /><br />TFF maximaliseert de slaagkans van je project door:
<ul>
    <li><b>35 jaar ervaring</b> in slimme materiaalcombinaties</li>
    <li>maximaal <b>draagvlak </b>bij je medewerkers</li>
    <li>bewezen expertise in<b> technieken en processen</b></li>
</ul>
<a class="bttn" title="Slimme materiaalinnovatie" href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/materiaalinnovatie/">Ontdek ons aanbod</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide { 
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ebebeb;
    margin-left:-100%;
    margin-right:-100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    height: 465px;
    }

.odd {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    clear:both;
    width:900px;
    padding:40px 0 27px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

.hometext {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}

.homeimage {
        margin-top: 0px;
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!
Stefaan

Comment: A quick fix would be to add `overflow:hidden` on `#bdywrapper2`. This is not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: overflow is only hiding the problem at my point of view. See my answer, its a nice solution and you can see a example in image working :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping out!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I've changed your html and css using firebug in real-time and it works look:**

[image: working solution]

Your problem is the html, your `.wide` div are placed on the wrong place, i've placed it correctly, and changed a little the `CSS`, use these html and css:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bdywrapper2">
<div class="wide">
<div class="odd">
<div class="homeimage"><img src="http://www.tff-bvba.be/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/hugo-home.png" alt="hugo-home" class="alignright size-full wp-image-1283"></div>
<div class="hometext">
<h1>Slaag in je materiaalinnovatie</h1>
<p>Plan je een complexe innovatie waarbij de <b>combinatie en vorm van materialen</b> essentieel is? Missen je medewerkers <i>knowhow</i> of heb je tijdelijk versterking nodig?</p>
<p>TFF maximaliseert de slaagkans van je project door:</p>
<ul>
<li><b>35 jaar ervaring</b> in slimme materiaalcombinaties</li>
<li>maximaal <b>draagvlak </b>bij je medewerkers</li>
<li>bewezen expertise in<b> technieken en processen</b></li>
</ul>
<p><a class="bttn" title="Slimme materiaalinnovatie" href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/materiaalinnovatie/">Ontdek ons aanbod</a>
</p></div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Start of main -->
<div class="main">









<div class="clear"></div>

<!-- Start of dynamic loop -->
<div class="dynoloop">

<!-- ******************************************************************** This is the start of blog loop ********************************************************************-->





<!-- Start of one half first -->
<div class="blog_one_half_first">

<!-- Start of slider wrapper -->
<section class="slider_wrapper">

<!-- Start of slider -->
<section style="overflow: hidden;" class="slider">

<ul style="width: 800%; margin-left: -412px;" class="slides"><li style="width: 412px; float: left; display: block;" class="clone">
        <h3><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/testartikel-2/">Een tevreden klant vertelt…</a></h3>
        <br>
        <p>“Mayser/M.Pore ontwikkelt en produceert metaalschuimen voor toepassingen zoals LED-koeling. TFF beschikt over jarenlange ervaring op dit domein. Ze assisteren ons dagelijks op vlak van kwaliteit, productiviteit en creativiteit.”  &ndash; Manfred Jordan, CEO Mayser/M.Pore</p>
<p>Meer klanten</p>
        </li>


            <li style="width: 412px; float: left; display: block;">
        <h3><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/testartikel-1/">Daarom werk je met ons</a></h3>
        <br>
        <h2><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/waarom-wij/">Daarom werk je met ons</a></h2>
<p>1. Unieke ervaring: <b>materiaalinnovatie + bedrijfsvoering</b></p>
<p>
2. <b>Snelle terugverdientijd</b> door interim dividenden</p>
<p>3. Mensgerichte aanpak: <b>draagvlak bij stakeholders</b><br>
<a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/waarom-wij/" title="Waarom wij?" class="bttn-left">Overtuig jezelf</a></p>
        </li>

                <li style="width: 412px; float: left; display: block;">
        <h3><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/testartikel-2/">Een tevreden klant vertelt…</a></h3>
        <br>
        <p>“Mayser/M.Pore ontwikkelt en produceert metaalschuimen voor toepassingen zoals LED-koeling. TFF beschikt over jarenlange ervaring op dit domein. Ze assisteren ons dagelijks op vlak van kwaliteit, productiviteit en creativiteit.”  &ndash; Manfred Jordan, CEO Mayser/M.Pore</p>
<p>Meer klanten</p>
        </li>


    <li style="width: 412px; float: left; display: block;" class="clone">
        <h3><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/testartikel-1/">Daarom werk je met ons</a></h3>
        <br>
        <h2><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/waarom-wij/">Daarom werk je met ons</a></h2>
<p>1. Unieke ervaring: <b>materiaalinnovatie + bedrijfsvoering</b></p>
<p>
2. <b>Snelle terugverdientijd</b> door interim dividenden</p>
<p>3. Mensgerichte aanpak: <b>draagvlak bij stakeholders</b><br>
<a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/waarom-wij/" title="Waarom wij?" class="bttn-left">Overtuig jezelf</a></p>
        </li></ul>


<ol class="flex-control-nav"><li><a class="active">1</a></li><li><a>2</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a></li><li><a class="next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul></section><!-- End of slider -->

<!-- Start of clear fix --><div class="clear"></div>

</section><!-- End of slider wrapper -->

</div><!-- End of one half first -->

<!-- Start of one half -->
<div class="blog_one_half">

<!-- Start of slider wrapper -->
<section class="slider_wrapper">

<!-- Start of slider -->
<section class="slider">

<ul class="slides">


            <li style="display: list-item;">
        <h3><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/testartikel-3/">Een tevreden klant vertelt…</a></h3>
        <br>
        <h2><a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/onze-referenties/">Een tevreden klant vertelt…</a></h2>
<p>
“Mayser/M.Pore ontwikkelt en produceert metaalschuimen voor toepassingen zoals LED-koeling. TFF beschikt over jarenlange ervaring op dit domein. Ze assisteren ons dagelijks op vlak van kwaliteit, productiviteit en creativiteit.”  &ndash; Manfred Jordan, CEO Mayser/M.Pore<br>
<a href="http://www.tff-bvba.be/onze-referenties/" title="Onze referenties" class="bttn-right">Meer klanten</a></p>
        </li>


    </ul>


</section><!-- End of slider -->

<!-- Start of clear fix --><div class="clear"></div>

</section><!-- End of slider wrapper -->

</div><!-- End of one half -->

<!-- ******************************************************************** This is the emd of blog loop ********************************************************************-->

<div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- End of dynamic loop -->

</div><!-- End of main -->

<!-- Start of accent bottom -->
<div class="accentbottom">

<!-- Start of accent top -->
<div class="accenttop">

</div><!-- End of accent top -->

</div><!-- End of accent bottom -->

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wide { 
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ebebeb;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 465px;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt, i have changed the page in real-time and i see it working perfectly within the changes that i did below. see edit

Comment: You are right, I had not seen the .odd div under the .wide one.

Answer (score 3):

Try Below `CSS`

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
.wide {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 465px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: this really do not works, because the `.wide` `div` will never fit the whole screen because it is wrapped by another `div` that isnt `100%.`

Comment: but .main is under div.bdywrapper2 which is having 100% width. thats why I have changed .main width from 980px to inherit(We can use 100% as well). and setting .wide width:100% will fit the window exactly.

Comment: ah, you inherited a `100%` width. Better use `100%` as well, more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple changes will do the trick for you

remove
`margin-left:-100%;
    margin-right:-100%;` 
    from class `.wide` and give `odd` class `100% width` instaed of `900px`

Your CSS at present is stretching the bg....!!

**EDIT :**

edit after the comment : use a `wrapper` class to wrap your entire text and images, put `odd` to `width:100%`, this will ensure better compatibility and ease of CSS flow

**HTML**

```
<div class="odd">
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="homeimage">
      <img src="" class="alignright size-full wp-image-1283" />
  </div>
  <div class="hometext">
  </div>
 </div> <!-- //wrapper -->
</div><!-- //odd-->
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{width:90%;margin:0 auto} // this will center the div and not take whole width at the same time
```

Comment: the problem here is that the .odd content will use all the width example: image of the man will stick to the right of the screen.